# Python Argument Not Recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been writing a parser script in Visual Studio Code and have encountered some very weird issue.

The function below basically just gets the argument during run time.

```
def setArguments():
    argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Parse pTest Results")
    requiredArgs = argParser.add_argument_group('required arguments')
    requiredArgs.add_argument('-c', dest="cur_log", help='Latest pTest Results',action = "store", required = True)
    requiredArgs.add_argument('-p', dest="pre_log", help='Previous pTest Results', action = "store", required = True)
    requiredArgs.add_argument('-Vc', dest="cur_Version", help='Current Build Version', action = "store")
    requiredArgs.add_argument('-Vp', dest="pre_Version", help='Previous Build Version', action = "store")

    return argParser.parse_args()
```

I have double checked the launch.json file for the arguments to be passed to the internal terminal. 
However, I am encountering the following issue and couldn't figure out what went wrong.

```
'pTest_Parser.py' '-c pTest' '-p pTest2' '-Vc 123' '-Vp 111'

usage: pTest_Parser.py [-h] -c CUR_LOG -p PRE_LOG [-Vc CUR_VERSION][-Vp PRE_VERSION]
pTest_Custom_Parser.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -Vc 123 -Vp 111
```

Only the -Vc and -Vp arguments are not recognized, -c and -p are working fine

Comment: Works for me by running `python pTest_Parser.py -c pTest -p pTest2 -Vc 123 -Vp 111`

Comment: Are you sure that the script is actually in a function? You should edit your question to allude to that

Comment: I have made the modification to the question. I have tried removing the last two arguments and the code works fine. Which makes me wonder what is wrong with the last two arguments

Comment: @Mervyn try clearing the `*.pyc` files.

Comment: I was able to make the argument work by using -v instead of -Vc(dumped -Vp since I realized that it doesn't serve a purpose) I am not sure why this works though. I am assuming that only 1 character is allowed for "-" arguments. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Side note: I wasn't able to find the .pyc files(wasn't showing up in Visual Studio Code's explorer, I'm pretty much new to python as well), so I didn't make changes to them